# how to work with more actions in account object using macros

Tags: macros

how to work with account object using macros where as we can work with more actions in case object([tried in](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/service_macros/units/service_macros_define)). The trail head contains totally with case object and now I want to try with account, Contact and custom object also.

I created custom button in account object also how [trail head shows](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/service_macros/units/service_macros_bulk) to create buttons. But actions are not available in Macro for account object.

Now, I want to try with other than Case, Could any one suggest me how to work with account object also.

Comment: What did you try so far post here

Comment: As [trail head shows](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/service_macros/units/service_macros_bulk) for case, I created a button in account and added to its page layout. And i did the same for a custom object also.